# Overlay window drawing which appears in screen captures of other applications

Tags: windows, user-interface, mfc, window, gdi

We need to overlay a target window with a custom shape and tracks the position of the target window such that the overlay drawing always appears above it. Also, the overlay drawing should appear in screenshots taken using `BitBlt` or `PrintClient` by screen-capturing tools like Camtasia, Debut, etc. Also, moving the target window around should not leave traces of the drawing at earlier location. The target window is not made using our code.

So far we've tried several ways but each method has its problems:

**1) Layered Window:**

Using a layered window as the child/owned window of the target window is the easiest thing and it works. But the problem is on **Windows 7** and **XP**, layered windows do not appear in a `BitBlt` done without the `CAPTUREBLT` flag and the screen-capturing tools may call `BitBlt` without the flag, thereby skipping our window from the capture.

**2) Region Window:**

The crude approach to support all Windows versions then is to use a region window using `SetWindowRgn` and make the target window its owner. However, region windows are generally very slow in rendering complex shapes and also impact the performance of other windows, sometimes to the point of freezing the application. Region window also leaves traces on dragging the application window.

**3) Subclassing and Drawing on HDC:**

Another approach is to sub-class the target window and draw the shape on its HDC on the `OnPaint()` event inside the window procedure hook. The shape can be drawn on the desktop window instead too. The problem is that applications may draw without a paint event, like when some text is selected using the cursor, and such drawing may erase a part of the custom drawing. Tracking all possible paint events is not a good way to do this.

**4) Drawing continuously in a timer:**

The last resort is to draw the custom shape on the target window in a timer continuously so the drawing is always above the target, even on text selection. But this may show a bit of flicker when the text is selected. Not to mention, it is very performance heavy to draw constantly.

**Question**

What is the best way to achieve an overlay drawing which works on all Windows versions (since XP) at the same time appearing in screen-captures. We've exhausted all approaches. Is there some method I'm missing? Can the above mentioned ways be used with some improvement? Is DirectX an option? I'm looking for methods with fast rendering capacity to achieve this. Appreciate any help!

Comment: It seems you already found a solution, but are now obsessed with fixing buggy screen capturing tools along the way. Wouldn't it be more appropriate to let the vendors of the screen capturing tools know, that their tools are buggy, and have them implement the fixes, instead of trying to fix them from your end?

Comment: It's not as easy as you think. Not getting captured becomes a security issue for me, so I have to take care of it.

Comment: I didn't suggest that you should not take care of it. I merely suggested, that you do it the right way. Your application is not responsible for bugs in other software. Have the vendor(s) fix bugs in software that you do not own.

Comment: I realize that you suggested the elegant thing to do, but we have to fix a security issue nonetheless as older versions of the capturing tools which have not fixed the code become a problem for us.

I'm just trying to understand if there is any other/better way to achieve this beside the ones which I have found.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution to draw an overlay window, is to use a double-buffered technique GDI, just like in this example:
[Overlay Drawing in CScrollView](http://codexpert.ro/blog/2013/01/10/overlay-drawing-in-cscrollview-part-2/)

I have myself the same task, and the only solution was that one. Hope it help you.

Comment: The solution mentioned in your link is good for self-created windows. In my case, the windows reside in third-party applications and I have no control on their code. I don't think the solution would work for me.